# .Net Core Change Password Validator

Tags: validation, .net-core, react-redux, asp.net-identity, change-password

I'm very new to .net Core, I have a form that asks the user to change his password. And I need to check the validation in the back-end. The front-end in this case sends 3 params (UserID, Password, ConfirmedPWD).
What do I need in the back-end in terms of classes and controller ?

My web application is .Net Core 2.1 reactredux template.

Any Help is Appreciated

Validations :

1. *Must have 1 Alpha
2. *Must have 1 Numeric
3. *Minimum of 8, maximum 16

CustomPasswordValidator Class:

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator


{
    public int RequiredLength { get; set; }
    public CustomPasswordValidator(int length)
    {

        RequiredLength = length;

    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string item)

    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) || item.Length < RequiredLength)

        {
            List<string> errors = new List<string>() { "Password should be of length {0}" };
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed());

        }

        string pattern = @"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*0-9]{10,}$";
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern))

        {

            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed());
        }

        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the **FluentValidation** library where you can specify such complex scenarios declaratively.

```
Install-Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore
```

Your request class.

```
public class ChangePasswordRequest
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmedPWD { get; set; }
}
```

You can create your own validation class with fluent validation. You can also add your exception message.

```
public class ChangePasswordRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<ChangePasswordRequest>
{
    public ChangePasswordRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Password).Password();
    }
}

public static class RuleBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> Password<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        var options = ruleBuilder
                      .NotEmpty()
                      .NotNull()
                      .MinimumLength(8)
                      .MaximumLength(16)
                      .Matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$").WithMessage("regex error");

        return options;
    }
}
```

Some configurations...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddFluentValidation(fvc =>
                fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
}
```

Finally, you can check your model with **ModelState.IsValid**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordRequest request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using .net core, you dont have to explicitly check the ModelState like

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordRequest request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

The [ApiController] annotation over the controller will do the modelstate validation for you automatically. Give it a read and use it if you find it appropriate.

Comment: hi, what is the attribute you use to validate the password?

Comment: I think a good way to implement this would be to write a static method in a helper class that validates the password against the checks that you wish for and then call this validation method in some service rather than directly in the controller.